# Two menu items set as default; how to revert to just one?

Tags: joomla3.8

I have set 2 menu items as default by mistake (both have a yellow star), and it's not possible to change this, as I get the message:
"Save failed with the following error: At least one menu item has to be set as Default"
I don't understand this as there are now two menu items set as default, so i should be able to change one of them so that it's no longer "default", while leaving the other menu item as "default".
Now my menus don't work because of this.
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try going into your database, and going to the table `_menu`.

Make sure that only one menu item has the `home` value set to "1", and the others set to "0".

Pretty sure you shouldn't be able to have more than one default page, which suggests a database hiccup.

(Always make a backup before tweaking the database manually)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see any Joomla menus with "database"... I'm a complete beginner trying to learn...

Comment: I meant use phpMyAdmin, or whatever your hosting has, to access the database directly outside of Joomla.  There are some database management extensions for Joomla to do it in the admin, but I don't know how good these are.

Comment: Maybe try the menu Rebuild option first if you haven't already?